# How do I login to minio on private network with Pulumi

Tags: minio, pulumi

The plumi docs say you can login to AWS, Google and Azure S3 buckets. They also say you can use a local file with `pulumi login --local`.

They don't say how to login to a locally hosted minio server on a private network.

Anyone know if it's possible and if so, what is the format of the URL for `pulumi login`

Answer (score 0):

OK, I solved the problem and actually the docs do describe about connecting to S3 compatible storage.

Here is the command I use to connect

`pulumi login 's3://pulumi?region=uk&endpoint=https://api.s3.lab.soxprox.com&s3ForcePathStyle=true'`

The link to the AWS section of the docs is here. https://www.pulumi.com/docs/concepts/state/#aws-s3 It is discussed in the last paragraph of the AWS Section.